# why html dialog is always on top?

Tags: html, css

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px
}

dialog {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.box {
  z-index: 888;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <dialog>
    <p>Text</p>
  </dialog>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

I want the div to be on top of the dialog, so I set the z index high, but it doesn't seem to work at all. Any way to make the `div` appear on top layer ?

Answer (score -2):

Essentially , the dialogue element is not affected by z index since it is set strictly by the order by which the elements are added , kinda like an alert in JS which pop ups an alert window

Ill personally refer from using it ( dialog element ) and instead just create a div overlay

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).